# How to implement a dynamic group by in scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a `List[Map[String, String]]` that represents a table in a database, and a `List[String]` that represents a list of column names.  I'd like to implement the equivalent of a `group by` clause in `SQL` query:

```
def fun(table:List[Map[String, String]], keys:List[String]): List[List[Map[String, String]]
```

For example:

```
val table = List(
    Map("name"->"jade", "job"->"driver", "sex"->"male"),
    Map("name"->"mike", "job"->"police", "sex"->"female"),
    Map("name"->"jane", "job"->"clerk", "sex"->"female"),
    Map("name"->"smith", "job"->"driver", "sex"->"male")
)

val keys = List("job", "sex")
```

And then `fun(table,keys)` should be:

```
List(
    List(
        Map("name"->"jade", "job"->"driver", "sex"->"male"),
        Map("name"->"smith", "job"->"driver", "sex"->"male")
    ),
    List(Map("name"->"mike", "job"->"police", "sex"->"female")),
    List(Map("name"->"jane", "job"->"clerk", "sex"->"female"))
)
```

Comment: The types in your function definition aren't real types.  Can you provide some examples in order to clarify?

Comment: remove some typo and provide an example.

Comment: What have you tried?  You should really work on making your questions clearer and without mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `groupBy`:

```
table.groupBy(row => keys.map(key => row(key))) map { 
    case (group, values) => values 
}
```

Or more concisely:

```
table.groupBy(keys.map(_)).map(_._2)
```

Comment: I do know the groupBy function before,but I can't figure it out it can be solved this way. The solution is so elegant,many many thanks